# React native json parsing through Mysql

Tags: mysql, json, react-native, parsing

I am new to react-native. I need to display my JSON into my react native main page but I am not sure how to. Do you have any suggestions espiclay that the Json file is long. I want to display only "s_title":"hjkjhjk","s_description":"jnkmjhnkl" in an altarntive list view

JSON

```
Array [
  Object {
    "fk_c_locale_code": "en_US",
    "fk_i_item_id": 3,
    "s_description": "jnkmjhnkl",
    "s_title": "hjkjhjk",
  },
```

My Main React-Native page is the following where I need it to read from the Json file that:

```
import {
  Button,
  Alert

} 
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
};

function test(){
  fetch('http://***:3000/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => console.warn(users));
  //Alert.alert(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be your `jsonobject[0].s_title` and `jsonobject[0].s_description`.

Do check if it is undefined before assigning it; something like:

```
title = jsonobject[0].s_title === undefined ? "" : jsonobject[0].s_title
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below that worked. No need for parsing or anything!

The source was the networking info section at react-native page.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource:[]
     };
   }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://*****:3000/users")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
      this.setState({
       dataSource: responseJson
      })
    })
    .catch(error=>console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
    }

    render(){
     return(
      <View style={{padding:10}}>
      <FlatList
      padding ={30}
         data={this.state.dataSource}
         renderItem={({item}) => 
         <View style={{height: 50}}>
         <Text style={{height: 50}}>{item.s_description}</Text>
         <Text style={{height: 50}}>{item.s_title}</Text>
         <View style={{height: 1,backgroundColor:'gray'}}></View>
         </View>
        }
       />

     </View>
     )}
}
```